# Conversion of dates in swift without loss

Tags: ios, swift, date

**Goal/Problem**

I want to convert a `Date` into a `String` and back to a `Date`. I am able to do this but I am losing precision on the way. How can I make sure that not a single *bit* gets lost in the process?

`1573827905079978` vs `157382790508`

**Main code**

```
var now = Date()

var now_as_string = Date.dateAsString(style: .dayMonthYearHourMinuteSecondMillisecondTimezone, date: now)
var back_as_date =   Date.stringAsDate(style: .dayMonthYearHourMinuteSecondMillisecondTimezone, string: now_as_string)

print(Date.dateAsTimeIntervalSince1970WithoutDots(date: now))
print(Date.dateAsTimeIntervalSince1970WithoutDots(date: back_as_date))
```

**Output**

1573827905079978

157382790508

**Date Extension (the place where the real magic happens)**

```
import Foundation

extension Date {

    enum Style {
        case dayMonthYear
        case dayMonthYearHourMinute
        case dayMonthYearHourMinuteSecondMillisecondTimezone
    }

    static func dateAsString(style: Date.Style, date: Date) -> String{

        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = fromStyleToString(style: style)

        return formatter.string(from: date)

    }

    private static func fromStyleToString(style: Date.Style) -> String{

        switch style {

        case .dayMonthYear:
            return "dd.MM.yyyy"

        case .dayMonthYearHourMinute:
            return "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"

        case .dayMonthYearHourMinuteSecondMillisecondTimezone:
            return "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS Z"

        }

    }

    static func stringAsDate(style: Date.Style, string: String) -> Date{

        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = fromStyleToString(style: style)
        return formatter.date(from: string)!

    }

    static func dateAsTimeIntervalSince1970WithoutDots(date: Date) -> String{
        return String(date.timeIntervalSince1970).replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "")
    }

}
```

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43123944.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47502591/convert-a-date-absolute-time-to-be-sent-received-across-the-network-as-data-in/47502712#47502712

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Date is just a number of seconds, as a Double, since the reference date. (This is aliased to "TimeInterval," but it's just a Double.)

If you want it to be a string without losing any information, that's just the string form of the Double:

```
let nowString = "\(now.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)" // "595531191.461246"
```

And to convert it back, turn the Double into a Date:

```
let originalDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: TimeInterval(nowString)!)
originalDate == now // true
```

You definitely don't want to remove the decimal point. That's an important part of the number.

Comment: I am forced to remove any decimal points when I set this value to Firebase. It is the name of a parent. Therefore no decimal points allowed. Thank you for your answer though