# How to resolve error in unit testing when we have Date comparison in Codable

Tags: swift, unit-testing, date, codable

I tried to use custom date strategy in json decoding using `Codable` as describe in https://stackoverflow.com/a/28016692/3477974 . Here is the simplified implementation code:

```
public extension Formatter {
    static let iso8601: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXXXX"
        return formatter
    }()
}

public extension Date {
    var iso8601: String {
        return Formatter.iso8601.string(from: self)
    }
}


public extension JSONDecoder.DateDecodingStrategy {
    static let iso8601withFractionalSeconds = custom {
        let container = try $0.singleValueContainer()
        let string = try container.decode(String.self)
        guard let date = Formatter.iso8601.date(from: string) else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(in: container,
                  debugDescription: "Invalid date: " + string)
        }
        return date
    }
}


public extension JSONEncoder.DateEncodingStrategy {
    static let iso8601withFractionalSeconds = custom {
        var container = $1.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encode(Formatter.iso8601.string(from: $0))
    }
}
```

However, when it comes to unit testing it fails although the error message shows equal value used by `description` method of date:

```
    func test_jsonCodable_iso8601() {
        let dates = [Date()] // ["Feb 9, 2020 at 12:55:24 PM"]

        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .iso8601withFractionalSeconds
        let data = try! encoder.encode(dates)

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601withFractionalSeconds
        let decodedDates = try! decoder.decode([Date].self, from: data) // ["Feb 9, 2020 at 12:55:24 PM"]

        XCTAssertEqual(dates, decodedDates)
        // fails with error message: [2020-02-09 12:55:24 +0000]") is not equal to ("[2020-02-09 12:55:24 +0000]"
    }
```

Do you have any idea what is the issue and how we can resolve it?

By the way, the actual decodable object is the following one where `publishedAt` is of type date:

```
public struct NewsItem: Equatable {
    public let id: UUID
    public let author: String
    public let title: String
    public let description: String
    public let urlToImage: URL?
    public let publishedAt: Date
    public let content: String

    public init(id: UUID,
                author: String,
                title: String,
                description: String,
                urlToImage: URL?,
                publishedAt: Date,
                content: String) {

        self.id = id
        self.author = author
        self.title = title
        self.description = description
        self.urlToImage = urlToImage
        self.publishedAt = publishedAt
        self.content = content
    }
}

extension NewsItem: Decodable {}
```

Comment: The resolution of a DateFormatter is limited to milliseconds, compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/23684727/1187415, https://stackoverflow.com/q/43123944/1187415.

Comment: @SoheilNovinfard One way to work around your issue is to store on your struct the date after converting it to `String` and back to `Date`. Something like `extension Date { var iso8601LossLessStringConvertible: Date { Formatter.iso8601.date(from: Formatter.iso8601.string(from: self))! } }` and then you can use `Date().iso8601LossLessStringConvertible` instead of `Date()`

Comment: @LeoDabus Thank you I'll check this out

Comment: @MartinR Yes these links point out to the problem, but not the solution in this case. For keeping to use Date but be able to have this comparison I was thinking about private Date equal operator overload, but not sure if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

What you are testing is the date/string conversion so there is no need to involve JSON encoding and decoding into this. Start with a fixed date in string form, convert it to date and back and check the end result vs the fixed date

```
let input = "2020-02-02T19:10:23.123Z"

let formatter = DateFormatter.iso8601
let date = formatter.date(from: input)
let output = date?.iso8601

print(date != nil && input == output!)
```

Note that this was written in a playground and not as a unit test

Comment: I used in decodable object as I described at the end of question. It's a part of network parsing, it's not that simple

Comment: @SoheilNovinfard If you have tested the actual date parsing then you don't need to test that as part of your network parsing.