# nil NSDate from DateFormatter

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, dateformatter

I'm trying to convert String to NSDate with this code

```
let dateString = data as! String
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
let date = formatter.date(from: dateString)
let Calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.gregorian)
let unitFlags: NSCalendar.Unit = [.hour, .day, .month, .year]
let components = Calendar?.components(unitFlags, from: date!)
```

and `dateString` is `"2017-04-03T18:50:34.3042751+04:30"` but I'm getting `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` for the last line. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your date format doesn't match your dateString

Comment: `"2017-04-03T18:50:34.3042751+04:30"` should be `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSXXXXX"`

Comment: `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXXXX"` should work also

Comment: Don't throw force unwraps into your code - if there's a chance a value could be nil, handle it correctly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28016692/2303865

Comment: I'm currently debugging later I will do that thanks @AshleyMills

Comment: why `Z` at the end of formatter not working? @LeoDabus

Comment: The problem it is the missing milliseconds. Z or ZZZZZ would work also. check the image reference from the answer at the link above. I prefer XXXXX or ZZZZZ because it has the `:` at the timezone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your date format as below

```
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SZ"
```

Edit: If you want more precision the you can add two more `S` e.g.

```
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
```

`S` will work upto 3 times after that it won't work. If you need to parse fractional seconds after 3 decimal places then you need to see this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/a/27412262/468724

Comment: be aware that Z doesn't match the original dateString. If you get a string from the date using it would result in `"-0300"` instead of `"-03:00"`

Comment: Yes @LeoDabus you're right, but I guess OP just needs to parse the date